# angular $q.all usage with multi layer of angular repeat

Tags: angularjs, promise

i have this piece of code

```
var final=[];
$http.get('/Scenarios/List/'+ id).success(function(resp){
    angular.forEach(resp, function(value, key){
        var scenario ={};
        scenario.data=[];

        angular.forEach(value.samples, function(b, i){
            $http.get('/sample/One/'+ b.id).then(function(result){
                var id= result.temp_id;
                var temp ={};
                $http.get('/a/list/'+ id).then(function(result){
                    temp.a=result;
                });
                $http.get('/b/list/'+ id).then(function(result){
                    temp.b-resutl;
                });
                scenario.data.push(temp);
            })
        });

        final.push(scenario);

    });          

}); 

console.log(final); //no value
```

basically when i tried to get a "final" data for further parsing, i discovered it is empty. I think the problem could be due to the missing usage of $q.all, but i have checked many tutorials online, i cant figure out a proper usage of $q.all to solve my repeat usage of angular.forEach, in my case, there are two. Any thoughts?

Comment: can you show your response data `resp`? two or three items

Comment: {samples:[{description:'abac',id:1},{description:'ac',id:3}], id:3} thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to solve it like this, using `$q.all` is what you were missing as rightly mentioned in the question.

```
var final = [];

$http.get('/Scenarios/List/'+ id).success(function(resp){
    processSamples(resp).then(function(final) {
        console.log(final)
    })
});  

function processSamples(resp) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    angular.forEach(resp, function(value, key){
        var scenario = {};
        var promises = [];
        scenario.data = [];

        angular.forEach(value.samples, function(b, i){
            promises.push($http.get('/sample/One/'+ b.id));
        });

        $q.all(promises).then(function(result) {
            angular.forEach(result, function(res, index) {
                var id= res.temp_id;
                var temp = {};
                var childpromises = [];
                childpromises.push($http.get('/a/list/'+ id));
                childpromises.push($http.get('/b/list/'+ id));
                $q.all(childpromises).then(function(res) {
                    temp.a = res[0];
                    temp.b = res[1];
                    scenario.data.push(temp);
                    if(result.length === index + 1) {
                        final.push(scenario);
                        if(resp.length === key + 1) {
                            deferred.resolve(final);
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Notice how it resolves the returned promise once the uppermost loop is complete. Also, since there was no *verifiable* example provided, I might have left minor mistakes but it should probably give a good idea at least.

Comment: hi, i can say this answer changed alot of my understanding, but can you explain if(result.length === index + 1) {
                        final.push(scenario);
                        if(resp.length === key + 1) {
                            deferred.resolve(final);
                        }
                    }

Comment: @onegun It's probably not the best way.. but since inside `forEach`, we have async code, we won't know when our API calls are returned.. so those conditions are meant to find the last iteration of loop respectively for lower and upper `forEach`s and push our data to some related variables

Comment: @onegun and when we have both loops last iteration together, we resolve with our final outcome, which would be passed directly to `.then` of our function call

Comment: i have traced code bit by bit, but i think this part is not working, any console.write put inside this condition is not triggered

Comment: if(resp.length === key + 1) {
                                    console.log("haha");
                                    deferred.resolve(final);
                                }

Comment: @onegun can't say what's wrong without working example.. can you create a plunker and call local JSON files instead of actual APIs using `$http`?

Comment: i think the problem is need to change to  if(res.length === key + 1) instead of if(resp.length === key + 1) , all working now, thanks